# concept of extraspecial $p$ ring

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

By an extraspecial $p$-group we mean a $p$-group whose commutator subgroup and center coincides. Can we extend this similar concept in case of rings whose commutator subgroup (subgroup of $(R,+)$) which is generated by the set of all additive commutators $[a,b]=ab-ba$ coincides with $Z(R)$ which is the center (multiplicative) of the ring. If so can we see some examples.

I have tried taking matrices $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & 0  \end{pmatrix}$ where $a,b,c\in \mathbb Z_2.$ But the center and commutator subgroup donot coincide.

Comment: I think you made a typo in your ring. It is not closed under matrix multiplication, e.g. $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\ 1&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]^2=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\ 0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$.

Comment: This is a problematic idea to begin with for a few reasons. 

Firstly, notice that *no (nonzero) commutative ring* satisfies this condition. That's pretty bad!

Secondly, consider this. Your original example in groups talked about the commutator subgroup, which is at least a subgroup of its group. The set of additive commutators is not always an ideal, and maybe not even additively closed.

Comment: Using the ideal generated by commutators goes too far though: if this is equal to $Z(R)$ and $R$ has identity, then it's the whole ring, so that $Z(R)=R$. But that means the ring is commutative so that the commutator ideal is zero. Thus $R=\{0\}$. This leaves open the possibility of looking at the additive group generated by the commutators though.

Comment: If, in your example, you meant the ring of $2\times 2$ upper triangular matrices $T$ over some commutative ring $R$, then you found an example that fails the condition pretty spectacularly. For that ring, 

$$
Z(T)=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}a&0 \\ 0 & a\end{bmatrix}\mid a\in R\right\}
$$

And the set of commutators is 

$$
\left\{\begin{bmatrix}0&a \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}\mid a\in R\right\}
$$
Congratulations, the set of commutators is an ideal, but it has trivial intersection with the center!

Comment: For these reasons, I'm suggesting that more interesting questions might be versions of this where the commutator (set, subgroup, ideal) is *different from* (i.e. has intersection zero with) the center.

Comment: thank you for your valuable comments. so is there any way that we can say that such rings exists or not?

Comment: No examples came to mind, and I couldn't immediately see why they couldn't exist.